# Why some Android.mk files are ignored by "make droid"?

Tags: android, makefile

I have modified a part of Android sources. Say, in folder `bla/blabla/blablabla`, there is a file `Android.mk`. It includes several underlying `Android.mk` from subfolders of `bla/blabla/blablabla`. When I `cd` to `bla/blabla/blablabla` and type "`mm`" - everything is built perfectly:

library #1 -- OK, ..., library #9 -- OK

However, if I type "`make droid`" from the top of AOSP sources, then some shared libraries are not built:

library #1 -- OK, ..., library #6 -- OK, **library #7 -- IGNORED**, **library #8 -- IGNORED**, library #9 -- OK

What is the reason of such weird ignoring of underlying Android.mk?

Answer (score 1):

It was found that ignored libraries were not mentioned in corresponding make file in `build/...` folder. That's why `mm` worked, but `m` was ignoring libraries.